How can I provide custom data via API to Azure OpenAI Model
I have created a chat model using Azure open ai and providing it custom data source with help of container and Azure ai search, but this is static. And I am using that API in my app. But what I want to do is that. But now I want to Integration it such a way that the user can ask questions about it account like purchases, profile related things, orders, etc. so that should be dynamic. How can I achieve it
I want to provide custom data to Azure openAI via API and it will be dynamic

What is the response of your Api. Check this list of supported data sources https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/references/on-your-data?tabs=python#data-source

What you are looking for is function calling:

Function calling allows you to connect models like gpt-4o to external tools and systems. This is useful for many things such as empowering AI assistants with capabilities, or building deep integrations between your applications and the models.

Here are some links to get started.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/how-to/function-calling
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/how-to/assistant-functions?tabs=python

You could also leverage LangChain as described here, use Semantic Kernel or the Azure OpenAI SDK.
I created a workshop a time ago that demonstrates function calling using C#, Semantic Kernel and the Azure OpenAI SDK. It can be found here
